# Cómo usar Express-Flash-Messages en un render después de crear un usuario?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express

Estoy aprendiendo NODE con el libro *Get Programing with Node js* de Johnatan Wexler y en lección 22 se hace uso de express-flash-messages en la vista index

El conflicto radica en que los flash messsages de la vista index opacan a los mensajes que deberían aparecer después de crear un usuario y ser redirigido a la vista index

Para crear un usuario y ser redireccionado a la vista index las líneas son:

```
 create: (req, res, next) => {//Add the create action to save the user to the database.
    let userParams = getUserParams(req.body);
    User.create(userParams)//Create users with form parameters
      .then(user => {
        req.flash("success", `${user.fullName}'s account created successfully!`);//ESTE NO SE VE A MENOS QUE SE BORRE EL FLASH DE INDEX
        res.locals.redirect = "/users";
        res.locals.user = user;
        next();
      })
      .catch(error => {
            console.log(`Error saving user: ${error.message}`);
            res.locals.redirect = "/users/new";
            req.flash(
              "error",
              `Failed to create user account because:  ${error.message}.`
            );
            next();
          });
  },
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El código para acceder al index es así:

```
  indexView: (req, res) => {
    res.render("users/index",{
      flashMessages: {
        success: "Loaded all users!"//ESTE SI SE VE Y OPACA EL OTRO FLASH
      }
    });
  },
```

Cómo índico que el flash-message de index no debe ser utilizado si eres redirigido después de crear un usuario?

[image: Este es u flash que sí se ve]

Comment: Usa nombres de propiedad diferente. Por ejemplo "success" y "success-users".  y lo mismo al recuperarlos.

Comment: Intente esto        req.flash("success-users", `${user.fullName}'s account created successfully!`);//Respond with a success flash message. y no funciona